# How to find identify blocks that do not contain specific word between brackets

Tags: regex, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I'm new to regex, and I have a question. Is it possible to use regex to identify blocks that don't contain a specific word between two specific characters?

I want to highlight all blocks starting with action, part, systempart or field, followed by any character, followed by an opening bracket. Then highlight if 'ApplicationArea' is not contained until the next closing bracket.

I've been trying and this is what I could achieve:

```
(action|part|systempart|field)\((.)*(\s)*(\n)*(\{)[\s]*(?![\s]*(ApplicationArea.*))(([\s\S\r^}]*?)\})
```

But this is only highlights if ApplicationArea is the first after the opening bracket.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k89Y.png)

```
            field("Max. Dep Bases"; Rec."Max. Dep Bases")
            {
                ApplicationArea = Basic, Suite;
                ToolTip = 'Specifies the value of the Max. Dep Bases field';
            }
            field("Suggested Value to Adjust"; Rec."Suggested Value to Adjust")
            {
                ToolTip = 'Specifies the value of the Suggested Value to Adjust field';
            }
            field("Adjust Depreciation"; Rec."Adjust Depreciation")
            {
                ToolTip = 'Specifies the value of the Adjust Depreciation field';
                ApplicationArea = Basic, Suite;
                ToolTip = 'Specifies the value of the Adjust Depreciation field';
            }
```

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Answer (score 0):

If there can not be `{` and `}` between the outer curly's:

```
\b(?:action|(?:system)?part|field)\([^()]*\)\s*\n{(?![^{}]*\bApplicationArea\b[^{}]*})[^{}]*\}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xG0Rsw/1)

Another option could be matching the opening and closing curly's at the start of the string, and all linkes in between that do not contains ApplicationArea.

```
\b(?:action|(?:system)?part|field)\([^()]*\)\s*\n{(?:\n(?!}$|.*\bApplicationArea\b).*)\n}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sLj1iN/1)